# TensorFlow XOR code works fine with two dimensional target but not without?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

Trying to implement a very basic XOR FFNN in TensorFlow. I may just be misunderstanding the code but can anyone see an obvious reason why this won't work-- blows up to NaNs and starts with loss of $0$.
Toggles are on works/ doesn't work if you want to mess around with it.
Thanks!

```py
import math
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

HIDDEN_NODES = 10

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
W_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, HIDDEN_NODES]))
b_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([HIDDEN_NODES]))
hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W_hidden) + b_hidden)
#-----------------
#DOESN"T WORK
W_logits = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([HIDDEN_NODES, 1]))
b_logits = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden, W_logits),b_logits)
#WORKS
# W_logits = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([HIDDEN_NODES, 2]))
# b_logits = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))
# logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden, W_logits),b_logits)
#-----------------

y = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

#-----------------
#DOESN"T WORK
y_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

#WORKS
#y_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
#-----------------

cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, y_input)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
loss = cross_entropy
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)

xTrain = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])

#-----------------
#DOESN"T WORK
yTrain = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]])
# WORKS
#yTrain = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]])
#-----------------

for i in xrange(500):
  _, loss_val,logitsval = sess.run([train_op, loss,logits], feed_dict={x: xTrain, y_input: yTrain})

  if i % 10 == 0:
    print "Step:", i, "Current loss:", loss_val,"logits",logitsval

print sess.run(y,feed_dict={x: xTrain})
```

Comment: A couple of other nits: 1. `y = tf.nn.softmax(logits)` probably isn't what you want, as this computes softmax across each row of the logits, which gives `[[1], [1], [1], [1]]` (since there is only one element in each row). 2. I had to lower the learning rate to get this to converge reliably: a value of 0.01 worked fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** For this to work, you should use

```
loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(logits - y_input)
```

...instead of `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

The [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) operator expects the logits and labels inputs to be a matrix of size `batch_size` by `num_classes`. Each row of logits is an unscaled probability distribution across the classes; and each row of labels is a one-hot encoding of the true class for each example in the batch. If the inputs do not match these assumptions, the training process may diverge.

In this code, the logits are `batch_size` by 1, which means that there is only a single class, and the softmax outputs a prediction of class 0 for all of the examples; the labels are not one-hot. If you look at the [implementation of the operator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3972c791b9f4d9a61b9ad6399b481df396f359ff/tensorflow/core/kernels/xent_op.h#L107), the backprop value for `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` is:

```
// backprop: prob - labels, where
//   prob = exp(logits - max_logits) / sum(exp(logits - max_logits))
```

This will be `[[1], [1], [1], [1]] - [[0], [1], [1], [0]]` in every step, which clearly does not converge.

Comment: Is there a general cross-entropy function in the API--couldn't find one on the docs?

Comment: There isn't right now - in fact, `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` used to be (somewhat inaccurately) called `tf.nn.cross_entropy`, because it served a similar purpose, but it's more efficient when training to fuse the softmax and the cross-entropy calculations (and their backprop) in one op. If you want general cross entropy, the typical expression we use is `xent = -tf.reduce_sum(labels * tf.log(predictions))`.

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding something because replacing                         `loss = -tf.reduce_sum(y_input * tf.log(logits))` didn't work (after softmaxing logits)

Comment: Sorry - that expression I wrote is cross-entropy for multi-class `predictions` (batch x num_classes) and one-hot labels. For the two-class case where the output and the labels are a single probability per example, you can use `xent = -(labels * tf.log(predictions) + (1 - labels) * tf.log(1 - predictions))`, as long as `predictions` is between `0.0` and `1.0`.

Comment: Ah awesome I saw that expression somewhere, need to understand why that 1-labels*log(1-pred) drops out when doing batch but that is just my own misunderstanding ....and that worked!!!! Thanks man!

Comment: Glad it helped! (Also, to add to the other part of your question, if the logits are a batch x 1 matrix, and you pass them to `tf.nn.softmax`, the output will be a vector of ones, because the numerator and denominator of the softmax will be the same.)